# How to prompt user to change password in hawtio, post first time login?

Tags: hawtio

I am using hawtio version 1.5.10 o, and using wildfly users as hawtio users.
How to prompt the users to change password post first login using hawtio web?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such feature in Hawtio per se. The user credentials are managed by the login module / authentication server, so if it provides such a feature then you can use it to achieve this. For example, if you enable [Keycloak integration](https://github.com/hawtio/hawtio/blob/master/examples/keycloak-integration/README.md) then Keycloak should provide you with such a feature.